# How to resume audio player at paused time at onResume Android

Tags: android, position, android-mediaplayer, onresume, onpause

The following media player works, but everytime the activity is paused (for example the screen switches off or an incoming call), the media player starts at position 0, but not at the paused position.

Has anyone a hint, how to set the last played position in order to get the player resuming on this last position, when the activity is resumed?

MediaPlayer Activity:

```
public class PoiView extends ActionBarActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {


    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private double startTime = 0;
    private double finalTime = 0;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
    public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
    public TextView startTimeField,endTimeField;
    boolean isPrepared = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_view);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagePlay);
        pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagePause);
        startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStart);

        seekbar.setClickable(false);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStop);

        try {
            //mediaPlayer.prepare();
            int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(poiAudio, "raw", getPackageName());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
            isPrepared = true;
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = getResources().getString(R.string.audioerror);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.audio_play,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (oneTimeOnly == 0) {
            seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
            oneTimeOnly = 1;
        }
        endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                        toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
        );
        startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                        toMinutes((long) startTime)))
        );
        seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
        myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
        pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
        playButton.setEnabled(false);
    }


    private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
                                            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
            );
            seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    public void pause(View view){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.audio_pause,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
        startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
        // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            b.putDouble("starttime", startTime);
            //mediaPlayer.release();
            pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
            playButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (mediaPlayer == null)       {
        int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(poiAudio, "raw", getPackageName());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
        } else {
            //mediaPlayer.pause();
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
            mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (mediaPlayer == null)       {
            int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(poiAudio, "raw", getPackageName());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
            startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
        playButton.setEnabled(true);
        startTime = 0;
        seekbar.setProgress((int) startTime);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    }

    public class MusicIntentReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(
                    android.media.AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY)) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
                playButton.setEnabled(true);
                startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putDouble("starttime", startTime);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("starttime", startTime);

    }

    private void unbindDrawables(View view)
    {
        if (view.getBackground() != null)
        {
            view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.imagePoi));
        System.gc();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("starttime", startTime);
        if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.poi_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                Intent backrouteview = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                backrouteview.putExtra("route", routeSave);
                backrouteview.putExtra("titel_route", routeTitel);
                startActivity(backrouteview);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the content of the modifed main activity file src/com.example.mediaplayer/MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.mediaplayer;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   public TextView songName,startTimeField,endTimeField;
   private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
   private double startTime = 0;
   private double finalTime = 0;
   private Handler myHandler = new Handler();;
   private int forwardTime = 5000; 
   private int backwardTime = 5000;
   private SeekBar seekbar;
   private ImageButton playButton,pauseButton;
   public static int oneTimeOnly = 0;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      songName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
      startTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      endTimeField =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      seekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
      playButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      pauseButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      songName.setText("song.mp3");
      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
      seekbar.setClickable(false);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);

   }

   public void play(View view){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing sound", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mediaPlayer.start();
      finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
      startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
      if(oneTimeOnly == 0){
         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
         oneTimeOnly = 1;
      } 

      endTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) finalTime)))
      );
      startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
         TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
         toMinutes((long) startTime)))
      );
      seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
      myHandler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
      pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
      playButton.setEnabled(false);
   }

   private Runnable UpdateSongTime = new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
         startTimeField.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - 
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.
            toMinutes((long) startTime)))
         );
         seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);
         myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
      }
   };
   public void pause(View view){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing sound", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      mediaPlayer.pause();
      pauseButton.setEnabled(false);
      playButton.setEnabled(true);
   }    
   public void forward(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp+forwardTime)<=finalTime){
         startTime = startTime + forwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump forward 5 seconds", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }
   public void rewind(View view){
      int temp = (int)startTime;
      if((temp-backwardTime)>0){
         startTime = startTime - backwardTime;
         mediaPlayer.seekTo((int) startTime);
      }
      else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
         "Cannot jump backward 5 seconds",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

 }
```

Following is the modified content of the xml res/layout/activity_main.xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
      android:onClick="forward"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />

   <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
      android:onClick="rewind"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew" />

   <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:onClick="pause"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />

   <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:onClick="play"
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

   <SeekBar
      android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
      android:text="@string/inital_Time"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
      android:text="@string/inital_Time"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is the content of the res/values/string.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

   <string name="app_name">MediaPlayer</string>
   <string name="action_settings">Settings</string> 
   <string name="hello_world">Now Playing:</string>
   <string name="inital_Time">0 min, 0 sec</string>

</resources>
```

Following is the content of AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.mediaplayer"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <activity
         android:name="com.example.mediaplayer.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: At which Like should I look?

Comment: That page explains about how to create simple media player with pause and resume the mp3 file

Comment: Sorry, but I think, these code examples doesn´t really help me with my code. I´m new to Java. I´ve read the examples, but didn´t find any example, which refers to the activity lifecycle states.

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct, that you´ve only added a forward and rewind function? Is this the reason, why the currentPosition is not working after Resuming the activity?